# Using $n for n < 0 in Bison

Tags: c, parsing, bison

Is there a way in Bison to check the current token stack size?

I'd like to use ***$n*** with ***n*** as a negative number to access a semantic value of another rule but only if the stack is large enough.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a rule such as:

```
stmt:   ID '=' DIGIT
        { $$ = $3; }
    ;
```

The generated code fragment is:

```
{ (yyval) = (yyvsp[(3) - (3)]); }
```

The `yyvsp` 'array', therefore, is part of the answer.  Further up the (regular - not the GLR) generated code, you find that `yyvsp` is actually a pointer, not an array.  For example:

```
yyvsp = yyvs + yysize - 1;
```

It looks like `yysize` is the value you want; unfortunately, though, it is a variable local to a block which has terminated before the user actions are executed, so it is not directly available.  However, you can also find code with:

```
yyvsp = yyvs;
```

Looking at the code, it seems that `yyvs` is a pointer to the base of the stack (which can be dynamically allocated), and `yyvsp` is a pointer part way up the stack.  Those variables are both visible throughout the `yyparse()` function (and therefore, in particular, are visible within user actions.  And the answer you need is:

```
int nrules = yyvsp - yyvs;
```

It isn't remotely clean to poke at the source code like this, but it does get you an answer.

If you use a GLR grammar, you would have to examine whether a Bison GLR grammar has the same variables with the same meanings; it may not.